# Sitecore IP Geo location Service-Personalization with Geo-based conditions does not work in sitecore 9.1.0

Tags: sitecore-api, experience-analytics, personalization, geo-location

Sitecore Personalization using GEO IP is not working.

Geoip service is working fine but default sitecore rule for geoip based is not working.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: How do you know the service is working fine? Is your tracker enabled?